# Swift: how can I draw a square on MapKitView

Tags: swift, polygon, square

How can I use the swift code to draw a square on MapKitView?
 The width and height are 0.0025

Comment: Show your efforts, what have you tried so far? Describe your specific problem, so that someone can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

For drawing on that I would recommend you to use KML. Good example from Apple is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html).